# What \K do exactly?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have seen in some examples \K like here "[Replace by an "X" every 3rd character in a string PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70514053/replace-by-an-x-every-3rd-character-in-a-string-php)", but I don't quite understand what exactly it is needed for and I can't find absolutely any information on the web. Can you shed some light?

Comment: See https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html and https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#bsk

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So \K just discards the part from the match that is before \K, did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is a kind of a "lookbehind equivalent". Also, see https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#%5CK